# Why 'this' declared in a file and within a function points to different object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I have a script like this:

```
var test = function(){
    console.log('From test: '  + this);
};
console.log(this);
test();
```

Which I run using `node test.js`. And what I would expect from the script is for both `this` to point to global object, however only `this` within the test function points to `global` object. 
`console.log(this);` actually points to an empty object.

I am trying to understand why node.js has this behaviour and am I misunderstanding something about how `this` keyword works in node.js.